# cordova play service version adapter plugin issue

Tags: google-play-services, cordova-plugins, ionic4

Please anyone help me for this issue. I using ionic4 . When i build i receiving this error.

'Cordova Play Services Version Adapter' has detected an error. The following dependencies of 'Google Play Services' are not compatible:
You have an incompatibility of versions with the following dependencies of 'Google Play Services':

```
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.0'
- 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+'
- 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+'
```

It doesn't exists a version of 'Google Play Services' that includes all these dependencies.
All dependencies of 'Google Play Services' must have the same version.
The application may not compile.